# Number of roots of a Vandermonde like complex determinant

Tags: polynomials, determinants, several-complex-variables

I am originally interested in the determinant

$$
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}\exp(i\lambda_1\cdot x_1) & \exp(i\lambda_2\cdot x_1) & ... & \exp(i\lambda_n\cdot x_1) \\\exp(i\lambda_1\cdot x_2) & \exp(i\lambda_2\cdot x_2) & ... & \exp(i\lambda_n\cdot x_2) \\... & ... & ... & ... \\\exp(i\lambda_1\cdot x_n) & ... & ... & \exp(i\lambda_n\cdot x_n)\end{array}\right|$$
where $x_i\in \mathbb R^2$ and $\lambda_j\in \mathbb  N^2$.
It might be algebraically easier to study under the polynomial form
$$
F(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\det(z_i^{\lambda_j})$$
with the notation $(x+iy)^{(a,b)}=x^ay^b$. I have a set of $N$ points $x_i$ with $N$ much larger than $n$ and I would like to prove that for at least one subset of $n$ points $x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n}$  the determinant does not vanish. Unfortunately I am not knowledgable in polynomials of several variables. Do you see an argument that could help me?

**Remark:** I don't know if it can be of any help but the $\lambda_j$ are square roots of $N$ in the sense that $\|\lambda_j\|^2=N$.

Comment: This looks related to the $n!$ conjecture that was proved by Mark Haiman. See equation (3.1) at https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/nfact/msri.pdf.

Comment: Indeed this is exactly my formula, thanks. Now I have to understand this conjecture...

Comment: For further information see the survey article by Haiman  at https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/cdm/cdm.pdf.